# Postgres row_to_json produces invalid JSON with double escaped quotes

Tags: json, postgresql

Postgres escapes quotes incorrectly when creating a JSON export. Note the double quotes in the below update...

```
UPDATE models SET column='"hello"' WHERE id=1;

COPY (SELECT row_to_json(models)
    FROM (SELECT column FROM shaders WHERE id=1) shaders)
    TO '/output.json';
```

The contents of output.json:

```
{"column":"\\"hello\\""}
```

You can see that the quotes are escaped improperly and it creates invalid JSON.
It should be:

```
{"column":"\"hello\""}
```

How can I fix this Postgres bug or work around it?

Comment: I submitted this as bug #13160 to http://www.postgresql.org/list/pgsql-bugs/ (pending moderation)

Comment: It's not a bug. `COPY` isn't for outputting single results to a file. It emits escaped row-oriented data. It sounds like you want `psql`'s `\o` option instead.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is not JSON related. It's about the way text format (default) in `COPY` command handles backslashes. From [the PostgreSQL documentation - COPY](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/sql-copy.html):

> Backslash characters (`\`) can be used in the COPY data to quote data characters that might otherwise be taken as row or column delimiters. In particular, the following characters must be preceded by a backslash if they appear as part of a column value: **backslash itself**, newline, carriage return, and the current delimiter character.

(Emphasis mine.)
You can solve it by using CSV-format and changing the quote character from doublequote to something else.

To demonstrate:

```
SELECT row_to_json(row('"hello"'))
 | "{"f1":"\"hello\""}" |
```

```
COPY (SELECT row_to_json(row('"hello"'))) TO '/output.json';
 | {"f1":"\\"hello\\""} |
```

```
COPY (SELECT row_to_json(row('"hello"'))) TO '/output.json' CSV QUOTE '$';
 | {"f1":"\"hello\""} |
```

Comment: Could you explain what your suggested solution does there?

Comment: The solution is in the third line: `COPY (SELECT row_to_json(row('"hello"'))) TO '/output.json' CSV QUOTE '$';` and the only thing added to the not working version on the previous line is `CSV QUOTE '$'`. This changes to CSV format that doesn't add second backslash to backslashes unlike the default text format. In CSV the default quote character is double quote so that has to be changed to something else - dollar sign in this example.

Comment: but doesn't that mean that any dollar signs that I may have in my strings will be escaped with a backslash? I'm exporting a large table and there is actually no particular character that will not appear with 100% certainty. Can escaping somehow just be disabled?

Comment: The documentation doesn't mention the possibility to disable the delimiter altogether. It would probably be best to make this into a separate question.

Comment: Where is this separate question?

Comment: I don't think there's a separate question. Zoltán just posted a separate answer that deals with the case of not being able to use any specific quote character.

Answer (score 8):

The answer by Simo Kivistö works if you are certain that the character `$`, or whatever the special quote character you chose **does not** appear in your strings. In my case, I had to export a very large table and there was no particular character which didn't appear in the strings.

To work around this issue, I piped the output of the `COPY` command to `sed` to revert the double escaping of quotes:

```sh
psql -c "COPY (SELECT row_to_json(t) from my_table as t) to STDOUT;" |
  sed 's/\\"/\"/g' > my_table.json
```

The `sed` expression I am piping to simply replaces occurrences of `\\"` with `\"`.

Comment: I had success with a slightly different sed recipe: replace all backslash pairs with single backslash: `sed 's/\\\\/\\/g'`.

Comment: In newer versions of Postgres (since 9.3 I believe), you can also include a filter in the COPY statement like `COPY (SELECT row_to_json(t) from my_table as t) TO PROGRAM $$sed 's/\\\\/\\/g' > my_table.json$$`

Answer (score 0):

This combination of [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-copy.html) `COPY ... TO PROGRAM` and `sed` escaped properly the double quotes in a `json` compressed `gzip` data dump

```sql
\copy (
 SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(T)) :: text FROM (
  SELECT title, author, year FROM books WHERE category NOT LIKE 'fiction'
 ) AS T
) TO PROGRAM 
'sed ''s~\\\\~\\~g'' | gzip > ./books-`date +"%Y%m%d_%H%M%S"`.json.gz' ;
```